# I have a problem getting response on websocket

Tags: c#, websocket

I use the websocket API for speech recognition.
I send audio to the server and receive a response.
With this websocket API, it is possible to obtain voice recognition results while streaming voice data.
I can get the final recognition result, but I can not get the recognition result on the way.

The following shows the referenced code.
https://gist.github.com/arjun-g/75961830d363cc9265e4ac2ca095168b

After various trials, I found that line:85 was a problem.
This part seems to be waiting for the final result.

I may not have received the result on the way at all.

Please tell me why I can't get result on the way.

```
private async Task Connect(ClientWebSocket clientWebSocket)
        {
            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            clientWebSocket.Options.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {this.accessToken}");        
            Uri connection = new Uri($"wss://hogehoge");
            await clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(connection, cts.Token);
        }
```

The above is the part of the connect method.

Here is my whole code.

```
private async Task Connect(ClientWebSocket clientWebSocket)
        {

            CancellationTokenSource cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
            clientWebSocket.Options.SetRequestHeader("Authorization", $"Bearer {this.accessToken}");
            Uri connection = new Uri($"wss://hogehoge");
            await clientWebSocket.ConnectAsync(connection, cts.Token);
        }

static async Task SendAudio(ClientWebSocket ws)
        {
            ArraySegment<byte> closingMessage = new ArraySegment<byte>(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(
            "{\"command\": \"recog-break\"}"
            ));
            using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("audio.raw"))
            {
                byte[] b = new byte[3200];
                while (fs.Read(b, 0, b.Length) > 0)
                {
                    await ws.SendAsync(new ArraySegment<byte>(b), WebSocketMessageType.Binary, true, CancellationToken.None);
                }
                await ws.SendAsync(closingMessage, WebSocketMessageType.Text, true, CancellationToken.None);
            }
        }

        // prints results until the connection closes or a delimeterMessage is recieved

private async Task HandleResults(ClientWebSocket ws)
        {
            var buffer = new byte[60000];
            while (true)
            {
                var segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer);

                var result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(segment, CancellationToken.None);

                if (result.MessageType == WebSocketMessageType.Close)
                {
                    return;
                }

                int count = result.Count;
                while (!result.EndOfMessage)
                {
                    if (count >= buffer.Length)
                    {
                        await ws.CloseOutputAsync(WebSocketCloseStatus.InvalidPayloadData, "That's too long", CancellationToken.None);
                        return;
                    }
                    segment = new ArraySegment<byte>(buffer, count, buffer.Length - count);
                    result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(segment, CancellationToken.None);
                    count += result.Count;

                }
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, count);

                this.textBox2.AppendText(message);

            }
        }

private async void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ClientWebSocket cws = new ClientWebSocket();
            await this.Connect(cws);
            await Task.WhenAll(SendAudio(cws), HandleResults(cws));
        }
```

Comment: Speech is broken into frames and you need a complete frame to be able to process a frame of speech.  Http does not partition the response to be compatible with the speech recognition library.  HTTP has two modes 1) Version 1.0 which is stream mode where the entire response is one message 2) Version 1.1 which is chunk mode.   To get the asynchronous method to work you would need to have the server use Version 1.1 and have a chunk length be the same length that the speech recognition library requires to process the frame.

Comment: The Speech recognition requires a minimum number of bytes to process frames of data for recognition.  The HTTP Response is returning speech that is a lot longer than the minimum.  So you code is blocking and waiting for the entire response before doing any Speech Recognition.  To be able to process speech without waiting for the entire response you would need to process the response in chunks.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. To process the response in chunks, How should I write it? Is ```var result = await ws.ReceiveAsync(segment, CancellationToken.None);
``` inappropriate? Please let me know if there is a site to be helpful.

Comment: Chunks is HTTP Version 1.1.  If you do not specify version in client request it defaults to server default version.   Not all servers support Version 1.1.  Some only support 1.1 and not 1.0.  You need to find out if API supports 1.1 so you do not need to wait for entire response.

Comment: Should I add a header specifying the HTTP version in the above connect method?

Comment: You can try.  Not sure if it will work.  Normally do something like this :            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("Enter URL Here");
            request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version11;

Comment: Thank you! I tried variously, but still it did not go well. But thanks to you, I learned a lot! I will continue to try.

Comment: Http 1.1 requires after each chunk to send next chunk message, otherwise, a timeout will occur.  If Client code doesn't not support sending next chunk, then solution will not work.  With 1.1 you also have to have code that sends correct frame data (including header and correct number of bytes) so the Speech Recognizer will not give any errors.

Comment: Thanks. I put the whole code. Could you point out any inappropriate points in the code? Is the method of sending data bad?

Comment: First the await on the AsyncSend does nothing.  There is a temporary buffer between app Event stack in windows and then a timer moves in Windows that moves the data to the ethernet card.  So the AsyncSend just moves data from one memory buffer to another.  The await on the ReceiveAsync is waiting for entire response to  be returned which is causing the code to wait for entire response before processing.  You would need to send to Recognizer the correct number of bytes and not wait for entire response.

Comment: I see! I understand little by little. So, what should I use instead of ```SendAsync```, and ```ReceiveAsync```?

Comment: Remove the Await for both SendAsync and ReceiveAsync.  The send you don't need to do anything.  ReceiveAsync you have to send receive data to the Recognizer after you receive partial data.  You probably need a custom AsyncReceive Event.

Comment: Ummmm, it's quite difficult. In the first place, it seems that I can not receive the results on the way. How to send audio may be bad. I will continue to try.